# debug variable value cakephp

Tags: php, debugging, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

How can I print out some debug output, like the contents of an array variable? I'm using cakephp and eclipse and can't seem to be able to do this. I am not talking about logging errors, just print some variable value. It might be obvious and really easy to do, but I can't find a way to do it.

Thank you

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are no dumb questions for someone learning. So here are your options :

- Anywhere in your code, place the following statement `debug($var);`.
  This works in Controllers/Views and Models as well.
- Alternative: use CakeLog::write(LOG_DEBUG, "..."); to log debug
  values
- To be complete, one should install the very helpful `DebugKit` plugin. [Get it from here](http://thechaw.com/debug_kit)

Comment: It's worth mentioning in your answer that debug level must be set to 2 in app/config/core.php `Configure::write('debug', 2);`

Answer (score 7):

First check in your core.php file inside config folder ..

debug mode is 2 or not..

```
Configure::write('debug', 2);
```

and you can print data , array ,

like this:-

```
debug($data);
pr($data);
print_r($data);
```

we have debuging kit also for cakephp, By this you can see your request, session, `$this->data` values,, url,

Answer (score 4):

All you have to do is to use cakephp [debug](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/931/CakePHP-Core-Configuration-Variables) function like

```
debug($arrayname);
```

Before that you have to set debug mode to 2 at **core.php** under **app/config** folder

Here is more detail about the [debug](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/931/CakePHP-Core-Configuration-Variables)